# Laravel multi paged view and session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I'm making quiz application. I have a multi paged view depends on user selection. Laravel's pagination is not saving previous pages inputs so is there any way to fix this problem? I'm using Javascript, JQuery to hide, show `<div>`s so is there any way to avoid this things. Cause If there is a 1 question there must be only 1 view but i have 5 `<div>`s.

1. Session?
2. ...

Comment: Yes, use session.

Comment: @HADI Yeah I think so too. So i can store all `requests` to array or something. But how do i submit them all. I'm just looking for some example sir. Can you give me little example of this? on Answer

Comment: After submitting to controller just get back your session `$value = $request->session()->get('key');`

Comment: Oh i see. Can you give me in this answer section. Then i can give you reputation. i guess.

Comment: Answer added brother!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laravel session https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session

For each quiz submission store them into session and for final submission just get back your session -

```
$quizData = session('quizdata');
```

Answer (score 1):

You must probably use the ajax. Save datas as cookie when pagination buttons are  clicked. I think this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: this should be comment you have a enough reputation why are doing this

Comment: So is it like. I'm putting inputs in cookie array or something. and when i click `submit button` I submit my cookie?

Comment: I thought about this question for 3 day. And i made it with jquery. Almost samething. I made with cookies. But could be a better solution. I am also following this question. Hope you got answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Old input` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input

You retrieve the data using the `old` helper

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```